# An application of matrix operation in control

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a time-invariant linear continuous-time system as follow
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x(k+1) &= Ax(k) + Bu(k) \\
y(k) &= Cx(k) + Du(k),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $x(k) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the state vector, $u(k) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is the input, $y(k) \in \mathbb{R}^r$ is the output. System parameters $A,B,C,D$ are constant matrices with appropriate dimensions.

Define $ B_i = \begin{bmatrix} A^iB &  A^{i-1}B &  \cdots & B \end{bmatrix}$ and
\begin{equation}
M_i = \begin{bmatrix} 
D & \\
CB & D \\
CAB & CB & D & \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots \\
CA^{i-1}B & CA^{i-2}B & CA^{i-3}B &  \cdots & D
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

I have a question with respect to $B_i$ and $M_i$, which comes from a literature.

[Question] **Why the following statements are equivalent:**

1. $ {\rm Ker}\begin{bmatrix}  M_i & 0_{r(i+1) \times n} \\ B_i & -I_n \end{bmatrix} \subset {\rm Ker}\begin{bmatrix}  0_{n \times m(i+1) } & G_{i+1} \end{bmatrix} $,
   where $G_{i+1} $ is a matrix of form $n \times n$.
2. $ {\rm Ker}\begin{bmatrix}  M_{i-1} & 0_{ri \times n} & 0_{ri \times m} & 0_{ri \times n} \\ B_{i-1} & -I_n & 0_{n \times m} & 0_{n \times n}  \\ 0_{r \times mi} & C & D & 0_{r \times n} \\ 0_{n \times mi} & A & B & -I_n
   \end{bmatrix} \subset {\rm Ker}\begin{bmatrix}  0_{n \times (m(i+1)+n) } & G_{i+1} \end{bmatrix} $.

There is a lemma in linear algebra with respect to this equestion as follow
\begin{equation}
{\rm Ker} L \subset {\rm Ker} P \Leftrightarrow \text{there exists a matrix $T$ such that }TL = P,
\end{equation}
where $L$ and $P$ are two matrices.

The literature says that simple matrix operations and the lemma above can give the equivalence of the two statements above. However, I still don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Note that if $G_{i+1}$ is invertible, then ${\rm Ker}\begin{bmatrix}  M_i & 0_{r(i+1) \times n} \\ B_i & -I_n \end{bmatrix} \subset {\rm Ker}\begin{bmatrix}  0_{n \times m(i+1) } & G_{i+1} \end{bmatrix}$ only occurs if $M_i = B_i = 0$, which seems strange. Perhaps this is meant to be a statement about the **left kernel** rather than the kernel. The left kernel of a matrix $A$ is $\ker(A^T)$.